# Using subprocess in Python to launch mkvmerge

Tags: python, subprocess

Hi i'm trying to run mkvmerge from my python script.
I'm using the subprocess module to achieve this.

```
    mkvmerge_args = [
        "mkvmerge",
        "test.h264",
        '-o',
        "test2.h264",
        "--timecodes 0:timestamp.pts"
        ]
    returncode = subprocess.call(mkvmerge_args)
```

Here is the code i'm working on. The problem is that last argument `"--timecodes 0:timestamp.pts"`

I'm getting an error saying

> Error: The file '--timecodes 0:timestamp.pts' could not be opened for
>   reading: open file error.

What i'm wondering is why subprocess is thinking that the last argument is a file.

Comment: Did you try the command in terminal yourself ?

Comment: Yes, running mkvmerge test.h264 -o test2.h264 --timecodes 0:timestamp.pts works just fine

Answer (score 1):

0:timestamp.pts needs to be on it's own line.

```
mkvmerge_args = [
        "mkvmerge",
        "test.h264",
        '-o',
        "test2.h264",
        "--timecodes ",
        "0:timestamp.pts"
        ]
```