# Function calling using class() not working when used to add video files with mkvmerge, FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mkv

```
import subprocess
filename = input('file name: ')
track1 = input('file name: ')
track2 = input('file name: ')
outputfile = input('file name: ')


class trial:

    #constructor of trial class
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename =filename
        self.track1 =track1
        self.track2 =track2
        self.outputfile =outputfile

    def mkvmerge(self):
        self.commandlist = [
            "mkvmerge",
            "-o",
            self.outputfile,
            self.track1,
            self.track2,
            self.filename

            ]
        return

    def runmkvmerge(self):
        self.mkvmerge()
        print(self.commandlist)

object = trial()
object.runmkvmerge()
```

//I learned about the **init** and class() so I used that to write this code but although it shows no error the script does not work. I am trying to add audio files to a video file using mkvmerge and the command is very simple but strangely it does not work//

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: lets say you want to add an audio file to a video file to make it dual audio, this code is intended to do that

Comment: this scrip is only adding string one to the next one, which package you try to use?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand by the term 'package'? Would you be able to tell me about it in detail? I am very new at coding.

Comment: @jiraiya_sensei - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486716) is a good place to start. Forget classes, first just learn how to run `mkvmerge` from python, period. Then, learn Python a bit by bit.